# Integration as a duality pairing

Tags: integration, manifolds, duality-theorems

I was reviewing a definition of a particular integral and was struck for the first time that it actually described a [duality pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_pair) between a vector space of integrable functions and a vector space of functions of bounded variation.  This is probably old news to people who've taken a differential geometry course, but learning it on my own it was a bit of a revelation.

With that in mind it seemed clear to me that the same sort of pairing would also happen for a vector space of (some suitable class of) integrable functions on a manifold and the space of differential forms on the manifold.

In Terrence Tao's pdf [Differential forms and integration](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/forms.pdf) he says

> We have seen that integration is a duality pairing between manifolds and forms.

It would be easy for me to think that perhaps he is talking about the same thing I was just describing, but then again I also believe Terrence Tao is probably pretty accurate with his words.

Is there actually a duality between **manifolds** and forms?

Manifolds apparently don't form a vector space, so it doesn't fit my understanding of what a duality pairing is. But perhaps someone can explain that I'm not using the right definition of "pairing" or that Tao already meant what I described before.

Or maybe I even have the wrong end of the stick with what I described before.  I'm not sure that one can specify ahead of time a useful space of functions to be paired with *any* single differential form.  Maybe the bilinearity properties of $B(f,g)=\int_M f dg$ only hold on a case-by-case basis, and not on entire vector spaces.

Comment: Tao also says in the article that "This duality is best understood
using the abstract (and much more general) formalism of homology and cohomology." Maybe someone could elaborate that.

Comment: @Jack ahh, yes, that’s probably pointing to the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this sounds like [Poincaré duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality).  The de Rham cohomology group $H^k(M)$ consists of equivalence classes of differential $k$-forms, while the homology group $H_{n-k}(M)$ consists of equivalence classes of linear combinations of submanifolds of codimension $k$. This is discussed in Bott and Tu section I.5.

Comment: @André3000 Likely: the wiki article even has a section called "Bilinear pairings formulation"

Comment: It might be worth reading about deRham's theory of *currents*, which incorporates (locally integrable) forms and (piecewise smooth) chains into a single universe.